# htaccess infinite redirect loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https

I have been facing this problem for last 2 months.
I have an htaccess file which I have put in the top hosting directory.
But as soon as I put it, it causes redirect infinite loop.
I was asked by the hosting company to check if I have any other htaccess file enabled.
But I have only 1 htaccess file in my whole hosting directory.

Here is the code of my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone guess the cause of the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Unlike the second rule where the URI matched is always non-empty, the / won't get matched again and continue to loop.